# How to fix llvm register increment error?

Tags: while-loop, llvm-ir

I've been trying to get the following ir for a while loop to run

```
define internal i32 @main() {
entrypoint:
  %0 = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %0
  %1 = load i32, i32* %0
  %cmptmp = icmp slt i32 %1, 10
  br label %loopBody
  ret i32 0

loopBody:                                         ; preds = %loopBody, %entrypoint
  %loopCond = phi i1 [ %cmptmp, %entrypoint ], [ %cmptmp1, %loopBody ]
  %printfCall = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* 
  @0, i32 0, i32 0), i32 10)
  %2 = load i32, i32* %0
  %addtmp = add i32 %2, 1
  store i32 %addtmp, i32* %0
  %3 = load i32, i32* %0
  %cmptmp1 = icmp slt i32 %3, 10
  br i1 %cmptmp1, label %loopBody, label %AfterLoop

AfterLoop:                                        ; preds = %loopBody
  br label %entrypoint
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
lli: ir.ll:20:3: error: instruction expected to be numbered '%3'
%2 = load i32, i32* %0
```

The instruction numbering seems consistent to me. And I don't see no unreachable blocks. Could the issue be the branching??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. The issue is the basic block `entrypoint` of the the main function had two terminating instructions, `br label %loopBody` and `ret i32 0`, meanwhile it's supposed to have just one. This messes with the IRBuilder register numbering that names the basic bock `loopBody` %2. The llvm compiler then expects the next unnamed thing to be %3. IRBuilder -- llc conflict.